# Is there any difference in functionality between iPhone4 black and white color?

Tags: iphone-4

I have to purchase iPhone4 for development purpose,so can anyone suggest me is there any difference between iPhone4 white color and iPhone black color? If yes which one is better choice for development purpose?

Comment: Functionality will be the same between the two colors.

Comment: not worth the down vote (but, definitely worth the close vote)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differences include.

1) Slightly modified camera (placement wise) (barely worth mentioning since its same quality).

2) And color.

So for development purposes it does not matter which one you choose.

[Source](http://ismashphone.com/2011/05/what-are-the-major-differences-between-the-white-iphone-4-and-the-black-iphone-4.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference, so you can pick the color you like most.